# When does an AnalyserNode have a buffer ready?

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

It's difficult to find information about the `AnalyserNode` in the MDN docs, so hopefully y'all can help: is there a way to tell when a buffer has been processed by the `AnalyserNode` and there's FFT data ready for me to view?  All of the MDN examples involve using the animation timer via `requestAnimationFrame`, which is good for visualizations but not for the audio analysis I'm trying to do.  I'd like to be able to get *all* of the FFT data, not just poll at the animation frame rate.  MDN lists some events but it doesn't actually explain any of them in the context of the `AnalyserNode`, and the FFT data isn't an output in the audio graph so I can't just connect the `AnalyserNode` to a `ScriptProcessorNode` and do what I need to do that way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get literally all the data from the FFT, there's no way to do that with the AnalyserNode; you can't grab that output at the right time consistently.  You'd be better off using an external FFT library like DSP.js.

Comment: Can that be used in real time?  The built-in `AnalyserNode` can actually be run at the audio rate since (I assume) it's implemented natively in C instead of in JS.

Comment: JavaScript really isn't that bad at basic math; it gets pretty well optimized.